# Google api to fetch the location history of a user

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-latitude

I am looking for a google api to fetch the user location history, I know google is storing users location history and we are able to track it from -

> https://maps.google.com/locationhistory/b/0

But is google providing an api through which we can access this user history through an app, I think google latitude used to that only but I am not sure and any ways it is shut down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no API that achieves what you're after. I don't even think the latitude API provided tracking for other users.

Logically it could be a bit of an invasion of privacy if it did exist. Most people don't read the T&C's or permissions when they install an app and it would be fairly easy to use this for the wrong purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no API ready for use one can build together a script based on Curl that sets the right cookies and retrieves the content like described by Terence Eden [[LINK]](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/2014/04/extracting-your-own-location-information-from-google-the-hard-way/).

Another way - although not well suited for an app - is to create an archive of your Google account information (select only location history information to keep it small) and therewith getting a Json-file with all location information.

Answer (score -5):

I have found this in the GOOGLE MAP website. there are other classes too Like Polygon. I didn't try this but Hope it will work.

```
// Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle    
 PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
            .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))      
// North of the previous point, but at the same     
    longitude.add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))      
// Same latitude, and 30km to the west    
            .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))      
// Same longitude, and 16km to the south    
            .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0));     
// Closes the polyline.    
// Get back the mutable Polylineenter code here
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```